# Magento 1.8 my account layout in chrome

Tags: magento

I am using Magento CE.  Using theme Perfectum but have customized it to meet our needs.  Everything seems to look great in Firefox and IE but the My Account, Login, checkout, basically all the 1column.phtml pages are messed up in Chrome.  The main column is pushed up into the header. Have tried to fix this with CSS and messing with 1column.phtml and customer.xml and cannot seem to figure it out.  Any help would save my sanity.  http://caffealamode.com/magento

Answer (score 0):

In styles.css file line number 6599 remove the margin-top:160px and margin:-160px -25px 0

EDIT:

remove this margin:-160px -25px 0; too it will work for you

Comment: Hmmm. Doing that removed the push-up. I tried just removing margin-top:160px and leaving in this margin:-160px -25px 0 but it doesn't work in chrome again.

Comment: I removed that and the padding line but now the push-ups are below the pic and should be over the pic.

Comment: The wrapper class having the box shadow. remove that.

Comment: No just doesn't seem to work no matter what I try. Losing my mind.